# Converting a servlet to JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, servlets

hi guys i have been asked to turn an old Java EE Web Application (JSP/Servlet, EJB, JPA) to a modern JSF application i have done most apart from the servlet,

the current servlet is :

```
@WebServlet(name = "StudentServlet", urlPatterns = {"/StudentServlet"})
public class StudentServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private StudentDaoLocal studentDao;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        String studentIdStr = request.getParameter("studentId");
        int studentId=0;
        if(studentIdStr!=null && !studentIdStr.equals("")){
            studentId=Integer.parseInt(studentIdStr);    
        }
        String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
        String yearLevelStr = request.getParameter("yearLevel");
        int yearLevel=0;
        if(yearLevelStr!=null && !yearLevelStr.equals("")){
            yearLevel=Integer.parseInt(yearLevelStr);
        }
        Student student = new Student(studentId, firstname, lastname, yearLevel);

        if("Add".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
            studentDao.addStudent(student);
        }else if("Edit".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
            studentDao.editStudent(student);
        }else if("Delete".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
            studentDao.deleteStudent(studentId);
        }else if("Search".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
            student = studentDao.getStudent(studentId);
        }
        request.setAttribute("student", student);
        request.setAttribute("allStudents", studentDao.getAllStudents());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("studentinfo.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

how can this be modified to a JSF bean ? what parts do i need to add and delete

the application is a simple application to add a student details to a database, it is jsut something so i can get more understanding of how a database works with jsf

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see, in your servlet's service method all is messed up in one place: getting request parameters, conversion, validation, performing logics and doing database operations. In JSF there are special component to perform any of these tasks:

- collection of request parameters (`request.getParameter(...)`) is transparently done by the Faces Servlet so that you don't typically need to mess with it at all;
- conversion is done by introducing your converter class to a particular component (`@FacesConverter`) or by using the standard ones;
- validation is performed by attaching one or more validators to a particular component (`@FacesValidator`) or by using the standard ones;
- performing logic is done by calling a method of a backing bean: depending on the component/situation you can attach action methods, action listener methods, value change listener methods or ajax listener methods. In your situation you've got the action method that returns a navigation case outcome (`public void action(String action)`);
- doing database operations is managed by the injected service (typically by an `@EJB` class) just the way it is done in the servlet.

Next, JSF provides for a collection of UI components (like `<h:inputText>`) whose state is bound to a model that is in turn represented by the backing bean (like `@ManagedBean`) with a known life cycle. JSF lifecycle consists of six phases (I won't go into the details here):

- Restore view (build or restore the view from HTTP request, incuding JSF component tree);
- Apply request values (collect submitted request parameters, convert their values if necessary and store them locally in component state);
- Process validations (validate component values according to the defined set of rules);
- Update model values (updates model values as bound by the components);
- Invoke application (invoke methods, including action/action listener/value change listener/ajax listener methods);
- Render response (render HTML and send it in HTTP response).

All of these phases can be linked to the operations handled by your servlet and decomposed. I would now like to add some comments on what's the JSF counterpart to the classic Servlet+JSP combo of yours.

1. `String action = request.getParameter("action");` etc.

   In JSF you don't need to do anything to collect these parameters as this job's transparently handled by the Faces Servlet.
2. `studentId=Integer.parseInt(studentIdStr);` etc.

   In JSF the conversions (getting request parameters as strings and converting them to other java classes) are handled by a specified converter of a UI component. JSF has some built-in converters (like `DateTimeConverter`), but you can supply a converter of your own by implementing [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) interface. You can attach it to a given component by specifying a `converter` attribute (like `converter="myConverter"`), by nesting a `<f:converter>` tag (`<f:converter converterId="myConverter" />` or by nesting a standard tag (like `<f:convertDateTime ... />`). It's worth knowing that some values will be coerced automatically for you.
3. `if(studentIdStr!=null && !studentIdStr.equals(""))` etc.

   This one is probably your way of stating that some of the request parameters are required to create the response. In JSF you do that by specifying a `required` attribute of UI components (like `<h:inputText required="true" />`).
4. `if("Add".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){ doThis(); } else { doThat() }` etc.

   Performing business methods is most typically done in action methods (like `public String action()`) that's bound to a command component (like `<h:commandButton>`): `<h:commandButton action="#{yourBean.someAction}" />`. Most typically we have one business action per a command button. Action method is a method in a managed bean JSF is aware of, though, you may pass the concrete action to the action method (like `<h:commandButton action="#{yourBean.action('someAction)}" />` with `public String action(String action)`).
5. `studentDao.addStudent(student)` etc.

   Database operations are handled in the same way in action methods: by invoking a necessary method on an injected service.
6. `Student student = new Student(studentId, firstname, lastname, yearLevel)` etc.

   You bind submitted poarameters to a model by specifying value binding of UI input components. So, first of all you prepare a model beforehand so that in your backing bean you've got a non-null `Student student` and later you bind JSF components to model values (like `<h:inputText value="#{studentBean.student.studentId}" />`). This part is perfectly explained in [noone's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19722326/1820286).
7. `request.getRequestDispatcher("studentinfo.jsp").forward(request, response);` etc.

   Action methods can return a String. This String is the navigation case outcome (view id) that is to be forwarded to. So, this is essentially equivalent to `public void action() { ... return "studentinfo"; }`. Also, `request.setAttribute("student", student)` is also handled transparently by JSF when it associates a bean with a view/request/session/application. You can of course feel free to bind other objects of your own as well. For this reason JSF exposes some variables in EL scopes and provides for access to the objects (view/request/session/application) to associate your parameter with.

Comment: Very nice explanation as well. I think yours should be the accepted answer because it's more generic and also covers some further topics like validation and converters. Together with my answer with example code the transition from pure servlets to JSF should be covered pretty well.

Comment: Thank you. That was the idea behind posting a follow-up answer.

Comment: @skuntsel, great answer man. A tip to be corrected: in the fouth point in first list, and in the seventh point in the last list: while you're talking about navigation case outcome, you should put String rather than void. Also, if you can add in the answer a tip about facelets that took place of JSP.

Comment: @Omar The action method was supposed to return a string, so that's a good spotting, thanks. The second point is worth to be added as well!

Answer (score 3):

This transformation isn't that easy. I assume that you already have the "infrastructure" going, because that would clearly be too much for one post. By infrastructure I mean all necessary libraries, correctly configured web.xml and so on.

The following is not exactly the same as your servlet, but it covers the basics and I'll leave it to you to guess how the edit and search might be done.

The `Student` class:

```
public class Student {
    private long studentId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // getters+setters
}
```

Our transformed servlet:

```
// this is how we make the bean known to JSF
@ManagedBean(name="studentBean")
@ViewScoped
public class StudentServlet implements Serializable {
    @EJB
    private StudentDaoLocal studentDao;

    // this object will be "automatically" filled with the values from our inputform on the xhtml page
    private Student student; // getter+setter

    // we have unique actions for everything... they are referenced from the xhtml page
    public String add() {
        // do your yearLevel logic here
        studentDao.addStudent(student);

        return "studentInfo.xhtml"; // forward to the next page
    }

    public String delete() {
        studentDao.deleteStudent(student.getStudentId());

        return "studentInfo.xhtml";
    }
}
```

We need an xthml page for the "GUI" of our bean and call it "student.xhtml".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head />
<h:body>

    <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{studentBean.student.studentId}" />
        <h:inputText value="#{studentBean.student.firstName}" />
        <h:inputText value="#{studentBean.student.lastName}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{studentBean.add()}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{studentBean.delete()}" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've got a very good practical answer (+1), but I decided to add yet another one in a more generic flavour.